# Как при наведении на объект, убрать отступы его родителя?

Tags: html, css

Верстаю по сетке бутстрап, есть ряд товаров, каждый обернут в .col-md-2 , нужно чтобы при наведении на один из товаров, его родительский блок .col-md-2 был без отступа. Как это сделать? Скрин ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете `border`при наведении на элемент, и вы хотите компенсировать это, убрав отступы у соседних элементов.

А можно просто использовать `box-shadow` вместо `border`:

```
.someBlock:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 3px orange;
}
```

Пример: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NikitaSmith/q6je12k7/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.product:hover {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#объект_на_который_наводишь').on('mouseover',function(){$(this).parent().css('margin','0');}
```